# django __unicode__() - how can i call this method in a template

Tags: django-models, django-templates

I defined a **unicode**() method in my Contact model.

```
def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

Now I want to show the return value of the **unicode**() method in a template.

But all that i try fails.

```
{{ object.unicode }}
```

or

```
{{ object.unicode() }}
```

or

```
{{ object.__unicode__ }}
```

or

```
{{ object.str }}
```

That confuses me since I have another Model level function which can be referenced to from the template without problems.

This works fine:

```
def get_id(self):
        return "%i" % self.id 

{{ object.get_id|escape }}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
{{ object }}
```

Will automatically return the value of  `__unicode__` for any object.

Comment: Great. Thanks. That works. But what do you mean with "(and some more characters so SO doesn't complain)"

Comment: SO requires a minimum of 15 characters in an answer or comment.