# How to get Object as String in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to do a very simple thing but I couldn't find how to.

I have this function defined in my model class :

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return "Object name = " + self.name
```

so in a template page, or in a views.py, I want to get this string.

in a template, I tried these and they didn't work :

{{ my_object }}
{{ str(my_object) }}
{{ my_object.self }}

What is the correct way of doing this?

Thanks !

Comment: Related and may be duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980862/django-unicode-how-can-i-call-this-method-in-a-template

Answer (score 8):

There is two functions `__unicode__` and `__str__` for python class.

`str` function, even in template, calls `__str__`.

```
class Object(object):
    name = "I'm an object"

    def __str__(self):
        return "Object name = %s" % self.name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"Object name = %s" % self.name
```